# SQL Merge Output Clause Error

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge-statement, output-clause

I have three tables:

1. source table
2. ODS table
3. Staging table

My merge statement uses source table to insert data into the ODS and Outputs into Staging table. After insert, the count of source table and ODS is the same, however, staging count is less than both. The output clause is supposed to insert a copy of what is being inserted in ODS into Staging but it's not the case. Does anybody know why that's the case? My merge statement is as follows:-

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
/* truncate staging table */
TRUNCATE TABLE stage table 

/* merge into ODS based on NK */
MERGE INTO ODS table as TRG
USING source table as SRC
/* ON Natural Key for that table/data type */
    ON TRG.column = SRC.column

/* insert new records into ODS */
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND SRC.column = @LOB THEN
    INSERT (columns )
    VALUES ( columns )

OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO STG. table

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Merge Output Clause Error

The problem was that the variable @LOB was a stored procedure variable so whenever I run the stored procedure by LOB it was truncating the staging table of the previous LOB data hence why the staging table had less data than both the source and target table.It's resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `;`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
/* truncate staging table */
TRUNCATE TABLE stage table ;

/* merge into ODS based on NK */
MERGE INTO ODS table as TRG
USING source table as SRC
/* ON Natural Key for that table/data type */
    ON TRG.column = SRC.column

/* insert new records into ODS */
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND SRC.column = @LOB THEN
    INSERT (columns )
    VALUES ( columns )

OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO STG.table;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

From [Merge doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql):

> **The MERGE statement requires a semicolon (;) as a statement terminator.**

---

Also `OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO STG.table;`  is huge antipattern, `*` and not defining column list

```
output inserted.col1, inserted.col2 INTO stg.table(col1_name, col2_name)
```

Comment: Thank you @lad2025 for your response but the problem was that the variable LOB was a store proc variable so whenever I run the Sp by LOB it was truncating the staging table of the previous LOB data hence why the staging table had less data than both the source and target table.It's resolved now.

Comment: @Hmen Notes about semicolon and `OUTPUT INSERTED.* INTO STG.table;` are still valid :)